# App build and make fails

Tags: software-installation

I want to install an app, [Zacros](http://zacros.org/). First, I have to install the Gfortran compiler. I have done that. After I have to follow these instructions.

*Compiling should be done using a terminal. It simply comes down to the following:*

```
cd path/to/source/of/Zacros 
mkdir build # If it does not exist yet 
cd build 
cp path/to/makefiles/makefile-gfortran-parallel-unix makefile make
```

After these procedure I am supposed to find zacros.x in the *build directory*
However the only thing I have is *No such file or directory*

Thanks for your help!
P. D. I have the academic version. So, I can freely use it. I do not know if I have to start from another user, super/user or something like this.

Comment: What do you want to install? It depends on how the software is shipped. Usually it is with `apt` command. In your case it seems you have [a tar.gz](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/349837)

Comment: I can't find anything either Google or zacros.org about installing this. Not sure why they wouldn't include this in their homepage. Perhaps because this is made for Molecular Biologists? https://xip.uclb.com/i/software/material_modelling/Zacros_evaluation.html

Comment: The software is called Zacros. It is used in physical chemistry. I have downloaded as .zip and later I extracted all the files.

Comment: So does the Zip contain a ReadMe file explaining how to build it?

Comment: The manual for installation is inside one of the folders once you download the files. The instructions I wrote above are exactly the ones stated in the manual for compiling the files.

Comment: You want us to download the 30 day evaluation? Please edit your question with the instructions they give you, nobody wants to register for that.

Comment: The last line `cp path/to/makefiles/makefile-gfortran-parallel-unix makefile make` looks like it needs to be 2 separate commands - either place the `make` on a separate line or separate them with a semicolon as `cp path/to/makefiles/makefile-gfortran-parallel-unix makefile; make`

Comment: "The version of Zacros made available under the Commercial Evaluation Licence is Windows executable functional for 30 days" So, even if we did get approval and downloaded it, it would do you no good

Comment: The first command is also suspicious; Linux convention is lower case, not capitalized, for directories. Please advise exactly what you typed when you substituted your path in the first line by clicking [edit]. Please do not use Add Comment; use [edit] instead to put that in your question.

Comment: The problem is that when I type the first line of instructions it displays *no such file or directory* so I cannot continue.

Comment: Why would this directory exist when you haven't created it yet? `cd path/to/source/of/Zacros` Just `mkdir Zacros` and put all your files in there.

Comment: That command is not intended to be run Verbatim, it just gives you a clue to edit it to your needs. If I may be so bold, I suggest reading up a little on Linux File and Directory tutorials and basic commands.